# d3.v4.js Line Graph with brush filter - Error: <path> attribute d: Expected number, "MNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNC…". and Expected number, "M0,NaNL0.1167307672…"

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to add a brush filter to my line graph and I follow this [example](https://bl.ocks.org/NGuernse/e203d6d4126377aadc733f3947b87421) but, I get errors.

> Error:  attribute d: Expected number, "MNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNC…".
>   Error:  attribute d: Expected number, "M0,NaNL0.1167307672…".

Here's my code:

```
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 110, left: 50},
    width = 900 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    margin2 = { top: 430, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50 },
    height2 = 500 - margin2.top - margin2.bottom;

var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d");

var x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]),
    y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]),
    x2 = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]),
    y2 = d3.scaleLinear().range([height2, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x)
    yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y)
    xAxis2 = d3.axisBottom(x2);

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

var svg = d3.select("#plot").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);

var plot = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "plot")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var slider = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "slider")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin2.left + "," + margin2.top + ")");

var line = d3.line()
    .curve(d3.curveBasis)
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.number); });


d3.csv("dataset.csv", function(error, data) {

  var brush = d3.brushX()
    .extent([[0,0], [width,height2]])
    .on("brush end", brushed);

  color.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) {
    return key !== "date";
  }));

  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.date = parseTime(d.date);
  });

  var countries = color.domain().map(function(name) {
    return {
      name: name,
      values: data.map(function(d) {
        return {
          date: d.date,
          number: +d[name]
        };
      })
    };
  });

  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
  y.domain([d3.min(countries, function(c) { return d3.min(c.values, function(v) { return v.number; });}),
  d3.max(countries, function(c) { return d3.max(c.values, function(v) { return v.number; });})]);

  x2.domain(x.domain());
  y2.domain(y.domain());

  plot.append("path")
    .datum(countries)
    .attr("class", "lines")        
    .attr("d", line);

  plot.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

  plot.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis);

  var country = plot.append("g");

  country.selectAll(".country")
    .data(countries)
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "country")      
    .attr("d", function(d) {
      return line(d.values);
    })
    .style("stroke", function(d) {
      return color(d.name);
    });

  slider.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height2 + ")")
    .call(xAxis2);

  slider.append("g")
    .attr("class", "brush")
    .call(brush)
    .call(brush.move, x.range());

  function brushed() {
    var selection = d3.event.selection;

    if (selection !== null) {
        var e = d3.event.selection.map(x2.invert, x2);

        var test = plot.selectAll(".country");
        test.classed("selected", function (d) {
            return e[0] <= d.date && d.date <= e[1];
        })

        plot.selectAll(".lines")
          .attr("d", line(
            data.filter(function (d) { return e[0] <= d.date && e[1] >= d.date; })
          ));
    }
  }

});
```

And this is a sample of my dataset(it's too big):

```
date,Albania,Andorra,Armenia,Austria,Azerbaijan,Belarus,Belgium,Bosnia And Herzegovina,Bulgaria
2005-01-01,3.446,3.671,-4.206,-2.775,1.137,-1.384,4.136,0.213,1.874
2005-02-01,2.257,2.695,-3.321,-4.726,0.463,-6.487,1.729,-1.492,-0.656
2005-03-01,7.271,6.856,2.788,0.994,5.689,-3.512,6.753,4.393,4.499
2005-04-01,11.485,10.308,10.032,7.286,11.847,8.084,10.391,10.248,10.36
2005-05-01,17.294,14.866,14.285,12.238,17.047,13.555,13.473,15.811,15.937
2005-06-01,20.165,20.264,17.723,15.518,20.635,15.768,17.995,18.599,18.293
2005-07-01,23.338,21.591,23.476,16.729,25.517,19.528,18.586,21.085,21.461
2005-08-01,21.928,19.788,22.649,14.81,24.131,17.452,16.905,18.998,21.001
2005-09-01,19.071,16.95,17.586,13.266,20.089,14.207,16.449,16.803,17.261
2005-10-01,13.412,13.817,10.424,8.319,13.177,7.485,13.622,11.447,11.173
2005-11-01,8.167,6.996,4.515,1.016,7.571,1.62,5.913,5.734,5.448
2005-12-01,5.131,1.919,0.874,-3.361,4.944,-2.699,2.782,1.786,2.728
2006-01-01,1.822,3.566,-5.34,-6.262,-1.433,-8.192,0.834,-0.999,-2.194
2006-02-01,4.094,4.108,-1.693,-3.009,2.31,-8.342,2.114,1.6,0.408
2006-03-01,7.838,8.464,4.863,0.098,7.183,-2.922,4.215,4.918,5.608
2006-04-01,12.538,11.472,9.841,7.314,11.629,7.324,9.084,11.314,11.099
2006-05-01,16.826,15.313,14.616,11.521,16.346,12.832,14.243,15.371,15.644
2006-06-01,20.294,19.307,21.928,15.63,24.331,17.092,17.391,18.668,19.27
2006-07-01,23.107,24.003,21.551,19.81,23.873,20.188,22.837,22.206,21.414
2006-08-01,22.6,19.595,25.291,13.915,26.676,18.018,16.55,19.208,22.229
2006-09-01,19.095,18.205,17.931,14.806,19.721,14.03,18.334,17.298,17.472
2006-10-01,14.799,15.087,12.034,9.613,14.837,8.517,13.763,13.252,12.843
2006-11-01,7.687,10.358,3.482,3.927,6.643,2.978,8.608,6.889,6.877
2006-12-01,5.023,4.534,-3.862,-0.032,0.431,2.382,5.17,3.13,2.741
```

It seems that it has a problem with: .attr("d", line), but I'm getting confused.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a way to get rid of those errors. If it helps someone else, I've changed this:

```
plot.append("path")
    .datum(countries)
    .attr("class", "lines")        
    .attr("d", line);

  plot.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

  plot.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis);

  var country = plot.append("g");

  country.selectAll(".country")
    .data(countries)
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "country")      
    .attr("d", function(d) {
      return line(d.values);
    })
    .style("stroke", function(d) {
      return color(d.name);
    });
```

To this:

```
      plot.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis);

      plot.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis);

      var country = plot.selectAll(".country")
        .data(countries)
        .enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "country");

      country.append("path")
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("d", function(d) {
          return line(d.values);
        })
        .style("stroke", function(d) {
          return color(d.name);
        });
```